# "ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing." occuring only in Gitlab hosted CI/CD pipeline

Tags: selenium, docker, karma-jasmine, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When running a CI/CD pipeline on Gitlab, my Karma tests are timing out with the error:

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
05 08 2019 22:25:31.483:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.2.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9222/
05 08 2019 22:25:31.485:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with concurrency 1
05 08 2019 22:25:31.488:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
05 08 2019 22:26:31.506:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
05 08 2019 22:26:31.529:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (1/2).
05 08 2019 22:27:31.580:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
05 08 2019 22:27:31.600:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (2/2).
05 08 2019 22:28:31.659:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
05 08 2019 22:28:31.689:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

This problem does not occur when running tests locally, and it does not occur when running the tests using the *same* Docker image with Gitlab Runner locally.

I feel like I have tried every possible configuration with `karma.conf.js`. I have Googled this issue relentlessly and have tried every suggestion from proxy servers, to environment variables, to flags... but alas, no luck. I have tried multiple Docker images as this was initially failing on local Gitlab Runner but I have found that the Docker image `selenium/standalone-chrome:latest` works fine in local Gitlab Runner.

Here is my `karma.conf.js` file:

```
const process = require('process');
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: [ 'jasmine' ],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/**/*.spec.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.spec.js': [ 'webpack' ]
    },

    webpack: {
      // webpack configuration
      mode: 'development',
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
              presets: ['env']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      stats: {
        colors: true
      }
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    reporters: [ 'spec' ],

    // web server port
    port: 9222,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // plugins for karma
    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-webpack',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-spec-reporter'
    ],

    // start these browsers
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-gpu'
        ]
      }
    },
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 5,
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 30000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout : 30000,

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: 1
  })
}
```

And here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
.prereq_scripts: &prereq_scripts |
  sudo apt -y update && sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash && sudo apt -y install nodejs

image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome:latest'

stages:
- test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - *prereq_scripts
  - npm install
  - npm test
```

I am expecting the tests to run successfully in all three instances (local npm, local Gitlab Runner and remote Gitlab CI/CD pipeline). Currently it only runs in successfully in the first two.

Comment: Same for me, its not working in azure devops pipelines.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, Puppeteer has an issue with Karma on Linux machines, see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/170)
There are plenty of solutions on how to make it works without Puppeteer if you use it just to install Headless Chromium.

I have installed it on my Jenkins Alpine machine using only two bash lines:

```
apk add chromium
export CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Alternatively, you can use Docker with the same setup. One of the examples is [here](https://github.com/Zenika/alpine-chrome/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 2):

In your `karma.conf.js` file you need to declare the CHROME_BIN variable inside the module.exports function:

```
module.exports = function(config) {

    const process = require('process');
    process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

    config.set({
    ...
```

Comment: That works locally, but it keeps failing on travis for example `Cannot start Chrome
 Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 86: unknown element "blank"`

Answer (score 1):

### Docker image with chromeheadless

for example, use a docker image of `angular/ngcontainer` with chrome headless for testing UI apps.

```
  image: 'angular/ngcontainer:latest'
```

Also, I created one docker image with the latest chrome

```
  image: 'anulals/angular'
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/angular/ngcontainer

https://hub.docker.com/r/anulals/angular